# destroy QHBoxLayout

Tags: c++, linux, qt

hello ever one here is my code i am calling all these statements in my button event handler like this

```
void analysis::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 myplot * p = new myplot(gao.structpayloadgraph,gao1.structpayloadgraph, gao.structcol-2, "payload");

    myplot * p1 = new myplot(gao.structsessiongraph,gao.structsessiongraph ,gao.structcol-2, "session");


  QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout;
 ui->horizontalLayout_2->addLayout(layout);
 layout->addWidget(p);
 layout->addWidget(p1);

}
```

myplot is graph plotting class
but the problem is that each time i click the button new graph appear and previous remains, like one !st click 2 appear on second they become 4 then 6......
how to i destroy QHBoxLayout in my button event handler

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create only one layout and after each click try to perform something like this layout->removeWidget(...); for removing prew graph.

Comment: thats what i am asking sir like i dont know about Qt functions

Answer (score 0):

Make your `layout` global for `on_pushButton_clicked()` function.

Then remove all previous widgets from it:

```
    QLayoutItem *item;
    QLayoutIterator it = layout->iterator();

    while((item = it.takeCurrent()) != 0) {
        layout->remove(item->widget());
        delete item->widget();
    }
```

After than you can add your widgets:

```
    layout->addWidget(p);
    layout->addWidget(p1);
```

**UPD:**
For [Qt3Support](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt3support.html) mode only.

**UPD2:**

```
    QLayoutItem *tItem;
    while (tItem = layout->takeAt(0) != 0)
        delete tItem;
```

Comment: sir its saying QLayoutIterator is not a type name although i have included #include"QLayoutIterator" class

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've pasted it from old qt3-code. You can use Qt3Support module or use `layout->remove(p)` instead iterating.

Comment: ok sir but the problem is still there where should i write remove(p). because new layout is creating on every click i need have to remove that layout i guess what should i do

Comment: I would avoid using Qt3 stuff, since in the next release it will be left out, so it means it would stop compiling.

Comment: yep, recomending "qt3 support layer" as a solution for Qt4 application is... nasty...

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like :

in your class :

```
class analysis{
```

private:
      ...
      QHBoxLayout* hLayouot;
      ...

public:
      ...
 };

in the constructor you have to create the object:

```
hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

--> if you can t put 'this' on constructor because your class doesn t hinerit from QWidget, you MUST delete hLayout inside the destructor!

while in your method `void analysis::on_pushButton_clicked()` you can call

```
hLayout->removeWidget()
```

..
i have experienced problem too removing from layouts: so i called hLayout->clear() and then re-inserted the objects!